# rails test not allowing to assert processing of before_action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

The following unit test succeeds in the first assertion, but fails in the second

```
test "login_name, kee and virtual_qr changed" do
  @user = users(:funky_mobile)
  assert_changes 'users(:funky_mobile).mobile' do
    @user.update(address: 'muuvt', mobile: '728363',   mobile_nation_id: 1)
  #   patch update_user_path(@user_mobile), params: { user: { address: 'muuvt', mobile: '728364',   mobile_nation_id: 1 } }
  end
  assert_changes 'users(:funky_mobile).login_name' do
    @user.update(address: 'muuvt', mobile: '728365',   mobile_nation_id: 1)
  end
end
```

*"users(:funky_mobile).login_name" didn't change.*
Note: while `patch` - attempted as per the following - does process correctly, it appears not applicable to a unit test.

The unit test with `update` only registers the submitted params but does not kick in the before_action, as per test.log

```
User Update (0.5ms)[0m  [1m[33mUPDATE "users" SET "mobile" = $1 WHERE "users"."id" = $2[0m  [["mobile", 728365], ["id", 165956397]]
```

Conversely, with an integration test

```
  sign_in users(:funky_mobile)
  assert_changes 'users(:funky_mobile).login_name' do
    patch user_url(@user_mobile), params: { user: { address: 'muuvt', mobile: '728364',   mobile_nation_id: 1 } }
  end
```

*"users(:funky_mobile).login_name" didn't change.*
*Expected nil to not be equal to nil.*

the changed data enacted via `before_action :set_user_login_name, only: %i[ update ]` of the `users_controller`

```
def set_user_login_name
  if params[:user][:email].present?
    params[:user][:login_name] = params[:user][:email].gsub(/\s+/, "")
  elsif params[:user][:mobile_nation_id].present? && params[:user][:mobile].present?
    @nation = Nation.where(id: params[:user][:mobile_nation_id]).first
    params[:user][:login_name] = @nation.phone_cc.to_s + params[:user][:mobile].to_s
    params[:user][:twilio_number] = '+' + @nation.phone_cc.to_s  + params[:user][:mobile].to_s
  else
    params[:user][:login_name]
  end
  params[:user][:kee] = SecureRandom.alphanumeric(32)
  params[:user][:virtual_qr_code] = params[:user][:login_name] + params[:user][:kee]
end
```

is processed as demonstrated by the test.log

```
 User Update (0.7ms)[0m  [1m[33mUPDATE "users" SET "login_name" = $1, "kee" = $2, "virtual_qr_code" = $3 WHERE "users"."id" = $4[0m  [["login_name", "39728364"], ["kee", "Rce8sQoH0VPvqUPeuegZL4gYVmJuamqi"], ["virtual_qr_code", "39728364Rce8sQoH0VPvqUPeuegZL4gYVmJuamqi"], ["id", 165956397]]
 TRANSACTION (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mRELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1[0m
 Redirected to http://www.example.com/users/165956397
```

Oddly, if the integration test is altered reomving assert_changes to simply

```
patch user_url(@user_mobile), params: { user: { address: 'muuvt', mobile: '728364',   mobile_nation_id: 1 } }
puts @user_mobile.mobile
  assert_equal(39728364, @user_mobile.mobile)
```

returns

```
3331112200
F [...]
Expected: 39728364
Actual: 3331112200
```

yet the log shows the same `User update` reference as above.

How can I properly assert that these changes are being carried forth?

Comment: Your question suggests you've got a `before_action` that you expect to be responsible for changing the login_name but haven't included it here. Without that, it looks like the tests are returning the correct results: the first assertion correctly finds that the `mobile` field has been updated; the second correctly finds that the `login_name` field hasn't been changed by the `#update` command.

Comment: That's correct for the unit test.  But update and patch demonstrably have different behaviours. With the integration test, according to the log, updates the record (but I have no way to assert it).

Comment: Thanks for the extra details on your `before_action`. What happens if you do the patch and then `assert_equal` your expected new value for the field? (It's no surprise that unit tests and integration tests have different behaviours, given they're based on different parent classes. I believe that 'official' recommendation is to use integration tests everywhere now.)

Comment: Yeah, I had tried that. To no avail (question updated) ; log still registers an update, but I see no way of asserting it.

Comment: So, if you use assert_equal then it shows the original field value? What happens if you make these updates at the Rails console? Can you change the values then? Are you sure the code's actually working (notwithstanding the log showing that *something* is happening!) and it's just the tests that are failing?

Answer (score 0):

This is going to fail...

```
assert_changes 'users(:funky_mobile).login_name' do
```

because...

```
users(:funky_mobile).login_name
```

returns the original value every time.  It is calling the fixture and acts like a constant.

What you should do is...

```
login_name = users(:funky_mobile).login_name
assert_changes login_name do
```

Comment: Good point, although it doesn't explain why the first `assert_changes` apparently passes, given it uses the same format.